# How to address a broken peach branch

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, damage, peaches

Yesterday I discovered a broken limb on a peach tree. My plan is to remove it properly in another week or so hopefully after the fruit ripens.

My question is how should this be addressed for the future health of the tree.  Is the exposed wood going to cause health problems?  Should I just leave it alone?  Or perhaps prune the entire branch back to before the break?

As you can see from the below images, there are a couple of branches below the break that could still thrive and the tear is about 8" long and maybe a bit less than 1/2 way through the branch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Time to put the break out of its misery with a cut close to the trunk. For the visual, spray brown paint over the wound (tar was used in the past.) Plants cannot repair themselves and our fixes are not permanent. For a consolation, consider that the remaining branches will produce bigger fruit for a similar total harvest weight.

Comment: Do ***not*** apply paint of any sort! In the future, do either or both of thinning the fruit earlier, and/or providing support to the branches before the fruit gets too heavy for them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I literally just drove in and commented how loaded that branch was looking with a plan to add some support.  Walked out a couple hours later and it was too late :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleanly cut off the broken branch as close to the trunk as you can. Don't bother with wound paints or covering the wound with anything. Let nature take its course. Trees want to heal themselves and (no guarantees, I'm afraid) the wound should heal itself over time. There's information (courtesy of Purdue University) on tree wounds and healing [here](https://www.purdue.edu/fnr/extension/tree-wounds-and-healing/).

EDIT
To be clear, cut off the broken branch at the point indicated in the photo below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks - can you elaborate on why this would be a better option than just cutting it back to the remaining branch below the break?  If you look at my first picture you will note there is a decently developed branch with fruit just below the break.

Comment: @Butthosenewbuttonsthough.. - You could do that, but it just seemed a shame to remove a reasonably sized branch.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost.  You are the one who said to cut it back "*as close to the trunk as you can*" - which would result in losing the branch.  I'm asking why you suggested that instead of just cutting it back to the branch.

Comment: I think you're talking past each other. Just cut off the broken part. If you don't regard the part that it broke off from as "the trunk" that's not obvious from the pictures. Cut the broken smaller part away cleanly from the upright larger part and let it heal.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - oh, thanks.  I get the misunderstanding now.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I guess I'm still a bit confused about how I can possibly make any kind of clean cut here since the entire break is such a long nasty tear. Are we just talking about snipping that tiny section which is still attached?

Comment: @Butthosenewbuttonsthough.. - I've added a photo to my answer.

Comment: @Peter4075 - thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

<to play the devil's advocate>
<disclaimer: I've never grown a tree, just seen it done>

Either after the fruit is ready or later in October when the tree is asleep:[image]

Advantages:

- healthy tree(given competent pruning)

Drawbacks:

- 10 large juicy peaches less next year